# Only shrink larger images using ImageMagick to a ratio

Tags: resize, imagemagick

Using ImageMagick, I can easily have a screenshot of what I want, but I'd like to resize it for using less space. I found this :

```
convert screen.jpg    -resize 1280x1024\!  screen.jpg
```

But I'd like to resize it based on the most bigger size (width OR height) and the other one (height OR width) will be proportionnaly resized too.

For example, say I want all my image to be resized to 600px at their most width/height size :

- 1920x1200 => width is the biggest : 600x375
- 600x1200 => height is the biggest : 300x600

How can I do that with ImageMagick?
(or at least, defining one max size (only width for example)).

Thanks for your help!

Note: is it possible to implement it automatically with the `import` command?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To preserve aspect ratio, you can shrink the image by a certain scale:

> convert -resize 50% screen.jpg

Or use a pixel area:

> convert -resize 180000@ screen.jpg

This would also blow up small images to the specified area. If you want ImageMagick to shrink your large images but keep small images untouched, use the ">" operator:

> convert -resize '180000@>' screen.jpg

Note that you then need to quote the geometry argument in order to prevent your shell interpreting the ">" sign as a file redirectors.

See ImageMagick documentation for these and other options: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

Comment: but by using your method, a smaller image will be resized too, right?

Comment: Right. I included that aspect into my answer above.

Answer (score 64):

To preserve aspect ratio:

`convert -resize 600x600  screen.jpg:`

- 1920x1200 => 600x375
- 600x1200 => 300x600
- 150x300 => 300x600
- 300x150 => 600x300

`convert -resize 600x600\>  screen.jpg:`

- 1920x1200 => 600x375
- 600x1200 => 300x600
- 150x300 => 150x300 (is not resized to bigger size)
- 300x150 => 300x150 (is not resized to bigger size)

Comment: Thanks so much for that. Didn't find it on the IM docs. Now found it here ;)

Comment: gives invalid parameter in windows! Any ideas?

Comment: On windows use ^ to escape it so -resize 600x600^>

Comment: For me it was missing the output file name

Comment: Replace `convert` with `mogrify` to overwrite the input file.

Comment: Or -resize "1150x1150>"

Comment: Is there a quality loss to the unresized images, e.g. from decoding and reencoding? EDIT: Apparently, yes- md5sum before and after does not match

Comment: This answer shows a more complex solution that leaves smaller images alone completely https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157594/18284